# Plot with Dsolve

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, manipulate

I am trying to plot the solution to the Dolve at a position /. x -> 0

```
Clear["Global`*"];
pde = D[u[x, t], t] == d*D[u[x, t], {x, 2}] + c;
bc = {D[u[x, t], x] == 0 /. x -> 0, u[L, t] == 0};
ic = u[x, 0] == 0.8*2800*9.8*(L - x);(*made up IC*)sol = 
 DSolve[{pde, ic, bc}, u[x, t], {x, t}];
sol = u[x, t] /. 
  First@Activate[sol /. {Infinity -> 10, K[1] -> n}]
```

Here is how to do it:

```
     Manipulate[Module[{pars, L0, x0}, {L0 = 3.5, x0 = 0.0};
  pars = {d -> d0, L -> L0, t -> t0, c -> c0};
  Quiet@Plot[
    Evaluate[sol/(0.8*2800*9.8*L0) /. pars  ] /. x -> 0, {t, 0, t0} , 
    PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 1.5}}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
    GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, PlotStyle -> Red, 
    AxesLabel -> {"t", "u(0,t)"}, BaseStyle -> 12]], {{d0, 0.01, "D"},
   0.001, 1, 0.001, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{c0, 0, "c"}, 0, 200, 
  0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{t0, 1, "time"}, 0.1, maxTime, 0.1,
   Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{maxTime, 1000}, None}, 
 TrackedSymbols :> {d0, c0, t0}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `SynchronousUpdating -> False`

> By default, Manipulate will time out if the contents take more than
> five seconds to evaluate

see https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SynchronousUpdating.html

Then the error goes away. But your Plot takes too long the way it is. When it now eventually completes, there is no error, but I see nothing in there even when I change the slides.  This is different issue.

I would suggest first make sure the plot is working OK **outside** Manipulate to test it. (use some values to test with)

Comment: I found a solution; see new edition

Comment: @Dave Yes that is better. I was busy and did not have time to look to see why your code was slow to plot. I was just trying to fix the cause of the aborted message which you asked about.

Answer (score 0):

```
Clear["Global`*"];
pde = D[u[x, t], t] == d*D[u[x, t], {x, 2}] + c;
bc = {D[u[x, t], x] == 0 /. x -> 0, u[L, t] == 0};
ic = u[x, 0] == 0.8*2800*9.8*(L - x);(*made up IC*)sol = 
 DSolve[{pde, ic, bc}, u[x, t], {x, t}];
sol = u[x, t] /. 
  First@Activate[sol /. {Infinity -> 10, K[1] -> n}](*/.x\[Rule]0*)
(*D[sol,t]*)
```

then

```
Manipulate[Module[{pars, L0, x0}, {L0 = 3.5, x0 = 0.0};
  pars = {d -> d0, L -> L0, t -> t0, c -> c0};
  Quiet@Plot[
    Evaluate[sol/(0.8*2800*9.8*L0) /. pars  ] /. x -> 0, {t, 0, t0} , 
    PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 1.5}}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
    GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, PlotStyle -> Red, 
    AxesLabel -> {"t", "u(0,t)"}, BaseStyle -> 12]], {{d0, 0.01, "D"},
   0.001, 1, 0.001, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{c0, 0, "c"}, 0, 200, 
  0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{t0, 1, "time"}, 0.1, maxTime, 0.1,
   Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{maxTime, 1000}, None}, 
 TrackedSymbols :> {d0, c0, t0}]
```